# How can I select rows from excel file by matlab, if these rows start with string its name (Vtotal:)

Tags: matlab

%%These two columns in excel file, I want to pick the rows which titled with (Vtotal:) and put all of them in vector.

`Column1   Column2
    Vtotal:          6135.1
    V2 Info:         1
    V3 Info:         1
    Labels_01:       26
    Vtotal:          5677.1`

Answer (score 0):

```
[m,b]=xlsread('filename.xls');

colhead=b(1,2:end);
rowhead=b(2:end,1);

inrow='Vtotal:';
incol='Column2';

irow=strmatch(inrow,rowhead);
icol=strmatch(incol,colhead);

m(irow,icol);
```